# How to bind data column to textbox?

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, binding

I have datagridview and textboxes on form. I load records from different tables when user clicks any one radiobutton. Data in grid is shown perfectly. I want to show values of the row in those textboxes.

One solution can be: binding data from dataset.
Second one can be: transfer values of each cell of row to respective textbox.

Please help me. And, please tell me which one is better or is there any other method which is even better than these two.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sir I done it making a simple WindowsForm with 2 radio buttons, 2 textboxes and datagridview
here is the sln file http://www13.zippyshare.com/v/98590888/file.html this must help u.

Comment: I got real help. Thank you Sir.

Answer (score 2):

```
Try using a BindingSource

BindingSource bindingSource = new BindingSource();
DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
DataAdapter da1 = new DataAdapter("Select * from Customers", conn1);
DataAdapter da2 = new DataAdapter("Select * form Orders", conn1);

da1.Fill(dataSet,"Customers");
da2.Fill(dataSet,"Orders");

//Let we set Customers table as bindiningSource datasource
bindingSource.DataSource = dataSet.Tables["Customers"];

private void RadioButtonCustomers_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     if(radioButtonCustomers.Checked==true)
        bindingSource.DataSource =dataSet.Tables["Customers"];
}
private void RadioButtonOrders_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     if(radioButtonOrders.Checked==true)
        bindingSource.DataSource = dataSet.Tables["Orders"];
}
//First param of Binding is to which prop of TextBox to bind the value
//Second param is the data source
//Third param is the data member or the column name of the table as datasource, so
//we have to get that table from casting the bindingSource datasource prop and casting it
//to DataTable obj and after that to take the ColumnName prop of the desired column

textBox1.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text",bindingSource,((DataTable)bindingSource.DataSource).Columns[0].ColumnName));
textBox2.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text",bindingSource,((DataTable)bindingSource.DataSource).Columns[1].ColumnName));
etc...
```

Even if you change the datasource prop of bindingSource, textboxes will remain binded to rowvalue of first and second column

Hope this help.

Comment: I tried this code and my observation is: 1. I get value of first row in textbox when I click another row. After this, the values do not change in textbox even when another row is selected. 2. It throws error when I click radiobutton2 and it attempts to set datasource property of bindingsource.

Comment: use  DataGridView1_SelectionChanged event and inside get the current row using bindingSource Position prop. After that assign datarow cell value to each textbox. Datarow dr = ((DataTable)bindingSource.DataSource).Rows[bindingSource.Position]; textbox1.Text = dr[0].ToString(); textBox2.Text = dr[1].ToString();

Comment: Sir, Assigning cell value to textbox was done by me without using bindingsource. Please see my answer below. I wish to know why values are not displayed after datagridview is clicked first time when I am using bindingsource as guided by you.

Answer (score 1):

I tried many options to display value in textbox on the same form, but it was not working as datagridview could display records of two different tables.

Instead, I used the following event of datagridview:

```
    private void dataGridView1_CellMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
    {
        this.dataGridView1.SelectionChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.DisplayValueinTextBox);
    }
```

In DisplayValueinTextBox, I wrote following code based on numbers of columns displayed for each table:

```
   private void DisplayValueinTextBox(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            textBox1.Text = dataGridView1.SelectedCells[0].Value.ToString();
            textBox2.Text = dataGridView1.SelectedCells[1].Value.ToString();
            textBox3.Text = dataGridView1.SelectedCells[2].Value.ToString();

            if (tblGrid == "Employee") //name of table which has more columns in grid
            {
                textBox4.Text = dataGridView1.SelectedCells[3].Value.ToString();
                textBox5.Text = dataGridView1.SelectedCells[4].Value.ToString();
                textBox6.Text = dataGridView1.SelectedCells[5].Value.ToString();
            }
            this.dataGridView1.SelectionChanged -= new System.EventHandler(this.DisplayValueinTextBox); //removed it as I was getting error.
        }
        catch (Exception exdisp)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(exdisp.Message);
        }
    }
```

I also changed SelectionMode property of dataGridView to FullRowSelect. This will ensure that textbox1 is displaying value of SelectedCells[0] even if user clicks any cell.

I still hope there is even a better option, so I wait for comments on this.